# Covariant wrapper for std::vector

Tags: c++, covariance

I want a covariant wrapper for `std::vector`.  My idea was to do something like this:

- Create an abstract base class `BaseVector<B>` whose `begin` and `end` methods just forward to pure virtual functions.
- Create a concrete derived class `DerivedVector<B, D>` that wraps a `std::vector<D>`.  Its `begin` and `end` methods would shadow the base class's, and it would implement the virtual methods that the base class forwards to.

In this way, if you have a pointer to a `BaseVector` you can iterate over base class instances, and if you have a `DerivedVector` pointer you can iterate over derived class instances.

(**EDIT**: Obviously the `BaseVector` will necessarily not support insertion, since it can't know the type of the objects it contains.  Perhaps this means "Vector" isn't the best name for it; I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks @CygnusX1.)

For the `DerivedVector` class the begin and end methods could just forward to `std::vector`'s.

**Question:** How could I implement the methods the `BaseVector` `begin` and `end` forward to?  Do I have to write my own iterator class that wraps the `std::vector` iterators?

**Alternatively:** Is there a better or easier way to do this?

A `DerivedVector<B, D>` instance needs to be usable through a `BaseVector<B>` pointer in code that knows about `B` but not `D`, and it needs to have equivalent performance to just holding a derived class vector (if the calling code knew about the derived class)

**Sample use case**:

A library provides a `BaseWidget` class and a `BaseWidgetPool` class, which the user derives from.  Due to the nature of the library, in any given program there will be exactly one `DerivedWidget` class, but this class will differ for every program using the library.

The `BaseWidgetPool` class includes methods that iterate over all the widgets in the pool and make use of their `BaseWidget` functionality.  But each program's `DerivedWidgetPool` is likely to want to use the `DerivedWidget` functionality of its contents.

(I know I could also handle this by making a generic `WidgetPool<T>` class, but I'd rather encapsulate `T` to the part of the code which actually uses it.)

Comment: IMO this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please note that iterator returned by `begin` and `end` also have to be abstract, so this idea could have any seance.

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this. I assume there's a specific context you have in mind where this might be useful?

Comment: In lots of languages this functionality is built in and you use it all the time.  I repeatedly run in to its absence in C++.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury doesn't mean it's the best solution to your problem and doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Can you show some example where this abstraction `BaseVector<B>` could be useful? This looks like problem with a app design.

Comment: If you want full functionality of `std::vector` you cannot do it, and for a reason! If you have your `BaseVector<B>`, are you allowed to `...::push_back(B)` into it? If there is a `std::vector<D>` undearneath - then the answer is no.
What you are trying to do makes sense only for an immutable vector, i.e. a view of some kind of it.

Comment: @CygnusX1 agreed, maybe not the best title.  I meant for `BaseVector` to be read only.

Comment: @MarekR: Added sample use case.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Added sample use case.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury thanks. I think my solution is still somewhat applicable to this case. Since you only need a view on the element and no insertion, ranges do very well with this. I could edit the question to add another example without the range library

Comment: @DanielMcLaury this is not an example. Example is a code showing desired code design. Anyway from what you have described template can handle that without any problems.

Comment: Indeed, if possible, and if it's not too intrusive, I'd go for the template solution.

Answer (score 3):

With ranges, this become a non issue. It has all the api you need for polymorphic ranges:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace rv = ranges::view;

int main() {
    std::vector<Derived> derived_container;

    // ... fill it

    ranges::any_view<Base*> base_view =
        rv::all(derived_container) | rv::transform([](auto& e) -> Base* { return &e; });

    // do stuff with `base_view`
}
```

Then you can use `base_view` as long as `derived_container` lives.

I used `any_view` so that the range is type erased. You can pass it around without needing to templatize function and you can pass it in virtual functions.

If you cannot use std ranges nor range v3, I'd create a simialar wrapper. So instead of a exposing a class herarchy, you hide it in the utility class.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/beta/z/yuju95)

Of course, the `any_view` is there only to avoid templating function over the range type when passing it around. You can instead directly materialize the range into a vector:

```
auto base_view =
    rv::all(derived_container) | rv::transform([](auto& e) -> Base* { return &e; });

std::vector<Base*> base_container = ranges::to<std::vector>(base_view);
```

This will avoid overhead during iteration but require a memory allocation for the new vector.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Does this necessarily incur a runtime cost when iterating over the view due to the lambdas?  I'm not really familiar with these things but looking at the generated assembly you linked I see three `call`s inside the loop, versus just one if I were to have a `std::vector<Derived> vect` and write `for(Base & b : vect) { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury yes there is overhead, but this is not due to the lambda. This is caused by the type erasure. `any_view` implements its iterator using a vtable. Each increment goes through virtual dispatch.